# Android Studio: Can't find class after refactoring it into a package: Didn't find class "package.VideoPlayerFragment" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, classnotfoundexception

My classes were getting too messy with everything being in one package, so I create seperate packages for fragments, activities, services, etc.. and moved the respective classes to the new packages. Now, when I run the application, it crashes. In the error, it's saying it can't find the fragment VideoPlayerFragment:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.VideoPlayerFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mypackage-ZtBOtHSaSvbICeciH5XL0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/mypackage-ZtBOtHSaSvbICeciH5XL0A==/lib/x86, /data/app/mypackage-ZtBOtHSaSvbICeciH5XL0A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

In the error it still says the old package name. The new one would be mypackage.fragments.VideoPlayerFragments. I don't know what to do... I already used "Clean Project" and I also tried deleting the .gradle folder but it still happens

Answer (score 0):

As usual, immediately after posting here, I find the issue. There was a usage of this class in a layout xml file that did not get renamed by Android Studio and was still using the old package name